# When is the right time to fetch a collection in Backbone js?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

So I'm working on a backbone app, and trying to modularize things as much as I can using require.js.  [This](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) has been my guide.

I'm having trouble getting my view to always fetch my collection.  If I access my app from the base url (`myapp.com/`), and go to the route of my view, the collection is fetched.  If I do not go to the view, and instead access it from `myapp.com/#/campaigns`, then the collection is not fetched.

Here is some relevant code.

**router.js**

```
    define([
  'jQuery',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'views/home/main',
  'views/campaigns/list'
], function($, _, Backbone, mainHomeView, campaignListView ){
  var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      // Define some URL routes
      'campaigns': 'showCampaigns',

      // Default
      '*actions': 'defaultAction'
    },
    showCampaigns: function(){
      campaignListView.render();
    },
    defaultAction: function(actions){
      // We have no matching route, lets display the home page 
      //mainHomeView.render(); 
    }
  });

  var initialize = function(){
    var app_router = new AppRouter;
    Backbone.history.start();
  };
  return { 
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```

**collections/campaigns.js**

```
    define([
  'jQuery',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'models/campaigns'
], function($, _, Backbone, campaignsModel){
  var campaignsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: campaignsModel,
    url: '/campaigns',
    initialize: function(){
    }

  });
  return new campaignsCollection;
});
```

**views/campaigns/list.js**

```
define([
  'jQuery',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'collections/campaigns'
  ], function($, _, Backbone, campaignsCollection){
      var campaignListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el:$('#container'),
        initialize:function(){
          this.collection = campaignsCollection;
          this.collection.fetch();
        },
        render: function(){
          var data = {
            campaigns: this.collection,
            _: _
          };
          $('#container').html('Campaigns length: '+data.campaigns.models.length);
        }
      });
      return new campaignListView;
  });
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  I believe it has something to do with calling `this.collection.fetch()` in the `initalize` function of the view.  If that is the issue, where should I put `fetch()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that your `campaignListView` fetch the collection when it is initialized and it is initialized only once. Your `render` method which is actually called from the router doesn't call your `initialize` method of campaignListView, when you change the`url` your second time.

You have two options here :

#### 1. return the class not the instance of your campaignListView and initialize it in the router :

```
// in your router code
showCampaigns: function(){
    var campaignListViewInstance = new campaignListView(); // don't forget the brackets after your initialize function
    campaignListViewInstance.render();
},

// in your campaignListView code :
return campaignListView; // without "new"
```

This will initialize the code everytime the router is hit.

#### 2. place your fetch in the render method

```
// in your campaignListView code :
initialize:function(){
    this.collection = campaignsCollection;
},
render: function(){
    this.collection.fetch({success: function(collection) {
        var data = {
            campaigns: collection,
            _: _
        };
        $('#container').html('Campaigns length: '+data.campaigns.models.length);
    }); // this will be fetched everytime you render and also it has success callback
}
```

Also be aware that you should replace all your instance creating functions with brackets at the end

```
return new campaignListView; --> return new campaignListView();
return new campaignsCollection; --> return new campaignsCollection();
```

Another problem you will face is the async work of `fetch`. You should use success or event driven rendering of your collection, because `fetch` works in the background and you will have no data when you immediately call render after calling `fetch`.

+1 for your AMD approach.

Answer (score 0):

I should really update the tutorial but it's better to not return instantiated modules. Maybe try checking out http://backboneboilerplate.com

Comment: Why is it better to return uninstantiated modules?  To save on memory?